# File dependencies in Gradle?

Tags: gradle

I am trying to specify some jar dependencies using gradle and these instructions:

http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:file_dependencies

I have the following project:

```
test
 -> libs
     -> svnant.jar
 -> build.gradle
```

where build.gradle contains:

```
dependencies {
  runtime files('libs/svnant.jar')
  runtime fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}
```

when I run gradle from windows cmd I get:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\...\test\build.gradle' line: 16

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'test'.
> Could not find method runtime() for arguments [file collection] on root project 'test'.
```

what have I missed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You only get a `runtime` configuration if you apply the `java` plugin (or declare the configuration on your own).

Comment: How to use this with the plugin com.android.application? They don't work together.